# How can I simply work around a missing JS property in an object in an object?

Tags: javascript

My front-end (not node) Javascript code either:

- has `process.env.version` defined

or

- doesn't define `process` at all (including `env` and `version` in there)

I need something simple to set a value if `process.env.version` isn't defined. This is my current code, which fails when `process.env.version is not defined.

```js
    if ( typeof process === 'undefined' ) {
        process.env.version = 'dev';
    }
```

I also tried this, no luck:

```js
    if ( typeof process.env === 'undefined' ) {
        process.env.version = 'dev';
    }
```

EDIT

This also fails, saying `process` is undefined:

```js
    if ( process && process.env && process.env.VERSION ) {
        var ver = process.env.VERSION;
    } else {
        var ver = 'dev';
    }
```

EDIT 2:

If it makes a difference, my code is run through Webpack, and the webpack config sets up the `process.env.version` variable. However, for dev I just run my JS directly in-browser, so that's why I'm trying to work around this if that variable is missing.

Comment: `process = { env: { version: "dev" } };`?

Comment: If I replace my if() structure with that line of code, seems like that would overwrite any existing value of `process.env.dev`

Comment: well, `process` is always available to NodeJs, and `env`, as well as that, holds the `NODE_ENV` variable that is needed to run Node, but normally we do `if( process && process.env && process.env.version ) `

Comment: You are looking to use `!==` instead of `===` - don't do the assignment only when it  is undefined, but when it is **not** undefined

Comment: @Bergi, nop.. Is `process` isnt defined. your `if (process.env.version !== foo)` will also return an error.

Comment: as @balexandre say, you're just trying to read this variable. So no need to update it, juste test all the path (using boolean conditions `process && process.env && process.env.version`

Comment: Ho here. yes okay you right ^^

Comment: I'm not using Node, it's front-end JS. I changed the code and still am getting an error. Will edit my question right now...

Comment: `var process = process || {}; process.env = process.env || {}; process.env.version = process.env.version || 'default';`

Comment: `var ver = (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process.env && process.env.VERSION) || 'dev';`

Comment: Hi @epascarello - that worked! Thank you! Can you post it as an answer to the question so I can give you proper credit?

Comment: Since your question was " set a value for process.env.version when it isn't defined." his answer is actually incorrect. Strictly writing.

Comment: @JavaScript good point, thank you

Comment: @JavaScript, OP can also miss understand what he's trying to do.. Updating a var to be able to read it is never good. whatever the reason

Comment: @Arthur also a good point, even though I didn't consider it fully-- yes, it is probably not smart to be updating the properties of `process.env` directly. So my revised code (setting `ver`) is a better way to go about it.

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, Mayhap OP likes eggs and mayhap not.

Comment: Moved to answer

Answer (score 3):

If your code is in a browser, then you might need to define a fake process object on the global object?

```js
if (typeof process === 'undefined') {
    window.process = { env: { version: 'dev' } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( typeof process === 'undefined' ) {
    process = { env: { version: "dev" } };
}
```

Comment: If OP just trying to read the var, you don't have to update anything.. Just read.

Answer (score -1):

First you should not update you original `process` variable only to be able to read it.

My solution for this is:

1-  You define a default version of the process variable, in order to always have at least this structure (and not have to test for validity every time).

2-  You add the `process` you receive to this (using spead in order to assign everything).

3-  Use you version of process instead of original.

```
// 1 Default: 
let defaultProcess = { env: { version: "dev" } };

// 2 Merge:
let proc = {
  ...defaultProcess,
  ...(typeof process !== 'undefined' ? process : {}),
}

// 3 Use:
console.log(proc.env.version); // dev
```

This way you will be able to use defaults values for multiple keys in a single time (and not only on path `process.env.version`)